# Over Partition for set column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I have this table, I need set ID column = 1 for the max value of column minutes, and the rest ID column = 0.

Initial table:

```
Register |minutes  | ID
10       |5        | 0
10       |6        | 0
10       |0        | 0     
12       |3        | 0
12       |0        | 0
12       |4        | 0
```

Final table:

```
Register |minutes  | ID
10       |5        | 0
10       |6        | 1
10       |0        | 0     
12       |3        | 0
12       |0        | 0
12       |4        | 1
```

Using Over Partition, any idea ?

```
UPDATE A
        SET ID = 1
        FROM
        (
            Select top 1 row_number() over (PARTITION BY     minutes 
            order by minutes asc)   AS column,*
            from table
        )A                  
        WHERE A.column=1
```

Comment: Please, tag your DBMS. Not all of them allow to update a subquery.

Comment: Why do you want to store this when you can always calculate it at runtime (and not have to worry about updating the stored value if any of the other rows change).

Answer (score 2):

You can use row_number() in an updatable CTE:

```
with m as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by register order by minutes desc) rn
  from t
)
update m set id=1 where rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
DECLARE @max INT

SELECT  TOP 1
        @max = Minutes
FROM    YourTable
ORDER BY Minutes DESC

UPDATE YourTable
SET     ID = CASE       
                 WHEN Minutes = @max
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END
```

Comment: I need group by, or make a partition, because is a combination of Register and minutes columns (please watch update)

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to use CTE or variable tables:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.ID = CASE       
                 WHEN B.RowNumber = 1
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END
FROM table A
JOIN (
   SELECT *, row_number() over (PARTITION BY Register 
      order by minutes DESC) AS RowNumber
   FROM table
) B ON A.Register = B.Register AND A.minutes = B.minutes
```

Comment: Why rejoin, you can update `B` directly

Answer (score 0):

I have left my previous answer in place as it represents the answer to the question as it was at the time of answering. Given the new information added to the question, the update query would be as below:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT  Register,
            Minutes,
            ID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Register ORDER BY Minutes DESC) RowN
    FROM    YourTable
)
UPDATE  MyCTE
SET     ID = CASE
                WHEN RowN = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
```